# On the finiteness of certain Zariski closed subsets of the prime spectrum of commutative Noetherian local rings

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, local-rings, zariski-topology

Let $(R,\mathfrak m)$ be a Noetherian local ring. Let $S,T$ be Zariski closed subsets of $\text{Spec}(R)$ such that if $\mathfrak p\in S, \mathfrak q \in \text{Spec}(R)$ and $\mathfrak p \subsetneq \mathfrak q$, then $\mathfrak q\in T$. If we also have $T\subseteq S$ and $T$ is a finite set, then is $S$ a finite set ?

Comment: Where does this question come from? What have you tried?

Comment: Anyways the answer is yes, even without assuming $T \subseteq S$